# How to create a table from another table that sums the sales by category?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table called 'Table' like so:

```
Person Amount
Alex:  $100
Alex:  $300
Julie: $50
Julie: $50
```

I want to make a new table that shows the total amount of sales for each person:

```
Person   Total Sales
Alex       $400
Julie      $100
```

I am new to DAX/powerbi so I really have no idea. I tried doing the below but it isn't working. Any help is greatly appreciated

```
Total Sales = var thisGRP = [Person]
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Table'[amount]),
    ALL('Table'),
    'Table'[Person] = thisGRP
```

Comment: What's your end goal? What will this table be used for? Why aren't you just creating a simple table visual on the canvas with the Person and Amount fields?

Comment: @JosWoolley I'm creating a dax formula to calculate commissions for salespeople and one of the criteria is client diversification (aka, salespeople with a lot of sales with one client are factored less in their total commission). Therefore, I want a table with all data grouped by client.

Comment: Have a look at the `SUMMARIZE` function.

Comment: @JosWoolley thanks. I am running into another problem. How do I filter using summarize? I want to create the table specifying a specific salesperson (Jack) and sales Quarter (2). I am using this: Group-by-table=SUMMARIZE('table','table'[clientName], "Total Sales", sum(Table[amount])), but it's giving me a sum of all client name sales for all salespeople and all quarters, not just quarter 2

Comment: This is why I asked what your end goal was. How precisely do you want to be able to filter this table? Or will it only every be for Jack? Or do you intend to create a separate table for each person?

Comment: @JosWoolley sorry! To be more specific, I want to create 3 buckets of profit diversification per client (let's say 0-100$, 100-200$, 200-300$). Let's pretend that Jack and Julie in this case are actually clients. Bucket 0-100 would have total 200$, and bucket 200-300 would have total $300.

Comment: I think it would be better all round if you changed your post to indicate your expected output. It's clear that the original, static output table you requested is not sufficient to meet you needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DAX [SUMMARIZE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/summarize-function-dax) function to create a new table.

```
Summary Table = SUMMARIZE(Table, Table[Person], “Total Sales”, SUM(Table[Amount]))
```